# Database not updating via DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, winforms, ms-access, datagridview

I am trying to update an access database via a `DataGridView` on vb.net without the use of a wizard.

However, I have encountered two primary issues:

1. When I attempt to save the content added to the grid, a message box displays the exception from a try catch saying `"DataTable already belong to this dataSet"`.
2. When I was able to make a changes without an exception the data got saved to the database, however when I later closed an reopened to the database and `DataGridView` the changes had been undone. Take note that the database has been placed in the bin/Debug folder.

Here is the code for the saving event:

```
Dim dataAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter
Dim DataTable As New DataTable
Dim DataSet As New DataSet
Dim Connection As New OleDbConnection

Private Sub btnsave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnsave.Click
    Try
        Connection.Open() ' the following decleration are used to save content to the table.     
        dataSet.Tables.Add(dataTable)
        dataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Students", Connection)
        dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable)
        Dim newRow As DataRow = dataTable.NewRow
        With newRow ' the with statement allows you do repeatedly apply a property to a certain object
            .Item("StudentID") = txtStudentID.Text ' these statements add the content of the text boxes to these respective fields in the database
            .Item("TeacherID") = txtTeacherID.Text
            .Item("StudentFirstName") = txtStudentFirstname.Text
            .Item("StudentSurname") = txtStudentSurname.Text
            .Item("StudentPassword") = txtStudentPassword.Text
            .Item("StudentGroup") = cbxStudentGroup.Text
        End With
        dataTable.Rows.Add(newRow)
        DataSet.Tables.Add(DataTable)
        Dim Command As New OleDbCommandBuilder(dataAdapter)
        dataAdapter.Update(dataTable) 'updates the table
        Connection.Close()
        ShowItems() ' displays the table

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Connection.Close()
    End Try

End Sub
```

If any more detail is required do ask.
edit: i found that the first issue is also prevalent when trying to delete something via the dataGrid, here is the code:

```
Private Sub btnDelete_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click
    Try
        dataSet.Tables.Add(dataTable)
        Connection.Open()
        dataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Students", Connection)
        dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable)
        dataTable.Rows(0).BeginEdit()
        dataTable.Rows(0).Delete()
        dataTable.Rows(0).EndEdit()
        Dim Commandbuilder As New OleDbCommandBuilder(dataAdapter)
        dataAdapter.Update(dataTable)
        dgrStudentDatabaseViewer.DataSource = dataTable.DefaultView
        Connection.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Connection.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: you probably dont need the access-vba tag if this is VB.NET.  you add the table twice just like the error says: once right after connection.open then again later

Comment: if you are referring to this section                          dataTable.Rows.Add(newRow)                   DataSet.Tables.Add(DataTable) , then i have removed that 'adding of the table' yet the problem persists.

Comment: `DataSet.Tables.Add(DataTable)` same exact line of code in 2 places.  if you get rid the Try/Catch it will show you the line causing the error - probably the second instance of that code.  Unless you will be working with multiple DataTables, you dont really need a DataSet

Comment: (re Edit) your dataset is a form level object - you cant add the same datatable to it over and over each time a button is clicked

Comment: In regards to bullet 2, saves are gone, the number one reason for this is the Copy to Output Directory setting on the database. See the following for options which I wrote since the many don't realize this. https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Working-with-Copy-to-11fbc251

Comment: Yes, thank you, you were correct. Any luck on the second problem?

Comment: Thanks Karen and Plutonix, your contribution seems to have solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
>  Public Sub fillDatatable(_datatable As DataTable, Query As String)
>     Dim sqlQuery As String = (Query)
>     Using conn As New SqlConnection("YourConnectionString")
>         conn.Open()
>         Using da As New SqlDataAdapter(sqlQuery, conn)
>             da.Fill(_datatable)
>         End Using
>         conn.Close()
>     End Using End Sub

Private Sub yourEvent()
    Using xDT As New Datatable
        fillDatatable(xDT, "Your Query;")
        yourDGV.DataSource = sssCompDT
        yourDGV.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill
        yourDGV.Refresh()
    End Using
End Sub
```

this should open display your sqlQuery results to a datagridview, see if it works on your end :D